# how to implement struts2 action error in the jquery grid page

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery

i have a jsp page with struts2 jquery grid. I want to show errors in the jsp page from my action class. 
To show error i am adding error messsage using

```
addActionError("You can not delete this  data");
```

code in my action class. And to display it i am using

```
<s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
   <div class="errors">
       <s:actionerror/>
    </div>
 </s:if>
```

code in my jsp page.  But unfortunately ,I am unable to show error in my jsp page. 
Please share your knowladge regarding this issue.

-Thank you
  Ashutosh

**Full Code:**

index.jsp:

```
.....
.....

    <body>  

    <s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
               <div class="errors">
                  <s:actionerror/>
               </div>
            </s:if>

        <div id="setpage"> <s:url id="editurl" action="nedit"/>
            <s:url id="editurl" action="nedit"/>
            <s:url  id="remoteurl" action="ntable"/>  

            <sjg:grid
               id="gridtable"
                caption="List of Subject Details"
                dataType="json"
                href="%{remoteurl}"
                pager="true"
                gridModel="gridModel"
                rowList="50,100,5000"
                rowNum="20"
 .....
 ......
```

My action.java

```
                  .........
                  .........
                  else
               {
                   addActionMessage("Unable to delete row");
                      return ERROR;
               }  
               return SUCCESS;
                   .........
                   .........
```

struts.xml

```
                 <package name="gridedition" extends="struts-default,json-default"> 
                            <action name="editionntableshow" class="v.esoft.actions.actionfile" >
                                <result name="success" type="json"/> 
                                                         <result name="error" type="json"/> 
                            </action>  

                       <action name="editionedit" class="v.esoft.actions.editiondetails.EditiondetailsEditAction"> 
                            <result name="success" type="json"></result>          
                        </action>
                 </package>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem...

```
<s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
  <div class="errors">
   <s:actionerror theme="jquery"/>
   </div>
 </s:if>
```

Comment: Isn't it just add `jQuery UI` style to your placeholder? How did it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

`jqGrid` submit the delete row action by `ajax`, while those `hasActionErrors` are not `ajax` operations so they cannot be caught.
In order to catch these action error/messages, that should not be a ajax/json action.

Comment: then what it should be ? please suggest a solution for this?

Comment: Are you insist to show it in your action error place holder or any other way is also ok for you?

Comment: i want   show it in my action error place holder .Please suggest me a solution for this.

Comment: From another way i know, declaring a variable in action class and performing its getter and setters and forwarding that error message in a seprate jsp page, and writing javascript Blah Blah Blah....

Comment: @AshutoshSingh Yes this is one way if you want to submit the changes non ajax way. It would be better if you can provide more information on how you do the editing. Is that inline edit or form edit using the navigator buttons?